# Supply bootstrap styleClass in richfaces modal panel

Tags: javascript, jsf, responsive-design, richfaces

Currently modal panel is having Fixed height and width which is failing on some devices like Mac 13"

Here is what I am doing to view the RichFaces modal popup panel.

```
<a4j:commandButton style="margin-left:15px;"
                   styleClass="btn yellow"
                   value="Options" onclick="if(isValidForm()){Richfaces.showModalPanel('optionPopupPanel',{top:'50px', autosized:'true', left:'150px', styleClass:'col-md-8'});return false;} return false;" 
                   ajaxStatus="noAjaxStatus"/>
```

I thought of supplying bootstrap class `col-md-8` using `styleClass` property to achieve responsiveness. This is not working and window width shown with very small width around 150px.

Width in % and making `autosized="true"` also did not help.

Appreciate any hint to make modal popup responsive or at least they do not run off the screen.

Comment: how about you simply overwrite RichFaces CSS classes with your own?

Comment: In firebug, I see classes like rich-mpnl-content, rich-mp-content-table, rich-mpnl-body etc.. I don't see any height-width specific styles there. However, Is it a good practice to overwrite in first place? What if I change the version of richfaces and class names changes in the next version? I am hoping for something very simple and controllable... Its not clicking though :)

Comment: Got to apply the dirty solution to override the RichFaces CSS class through jQuery and apply them onshow event of modal dialog.

Comment: Solution is not dirty - Richfaces is.

Comment: Ha ha.. .Agree with you legacy projects and got to live with that... :(